# How to install wine application for system wide usage

Tags: wine, winetricks, emulation

Can't figure out, whether it is possible to install an application via wine system wide to avoid repetitive process and save disc space.

Comment: You should be able to just make a shortcut of `/home/originaluser/.wine` in all the other accounts you want the programs in.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it be setting [WINEPREFIX variable](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wine) to a particular directory via `/etc/environment` *(i.e. to set the variable system wide)*. E.g. to have *myuser*'s installation system wide, add there a line like this

```
WINEPREFIX="/home/myuser/.wine"
```

Note however, that this way *every* Wine application would be installed «system wide», unless when you launch an app you explicitly set a separate WINEPREFIX, like `WINEPREFIX="/my/other/wine-dir" wine ./app"`